# Using Java, how do I delete two lines in a text file after reading them?

Tags: java, file-io, bufferedreader, outputstream

```
  try {

        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(
              new FileOutputStream("x.txt", true), "UTF-8");
        BufferedWriter fbw = new BufferedWriter(writer);
        fbw.write(newemails + ":" + passwordEntered);
        fbw.newLine();
        fbw.close();
        System.out.println("Poo");
    }catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

I am developing a program which creates accounts on a website and saves the details of these accounts into a text file. Then, another application reads this text file and extracts the account details. It is important for the application to not login in using the same account details. Therefore, I would like to make a program which deletes a couple of lines in the text file and then saves it, so that the application can log in using different account details. Above is the code I have for writing the email and the password to a text file.

Comment: rewrite the file with them lines in it

Comment: This sounds like a task for a database not a text file. You cannot really edit text files and just delete  a few lines out of the middle. The first option is to read the whole file, remove the text you want to remove and then write the whole file again. Another option (but much more difficult) would be to find the lines to remove in the file, and keep all the text before them, but re-write all of the text afterwards.

Comment: @matt Agree that a DB or a properties file would be a lot better solution